# Why class element nested in ID doesn't overwrite class element in other css file?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. Why does color definition in style.css not overwrite this one nested in ID: #main-nav?

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-nav" class="navbar-default" role="banner">
content
</div>
</body>
```

**bootstrap.css**

```
.navbar-default {
color: black;
}
```

**style.css**

```
#main-nav .navbar-default {
color: white;
}
```

What is interesting If I change code as below:

**style.css**

```
.navbar-default {
color: white;
}
```

Color parameter has changed. Can someone explain me why first way with ID doesn't work?

Comment: It's because of the Style Precedence in CSS, You can have more detail here : 
http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: No, it's because the selector isn't even matching in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) in your style.css file, meaning that your CSS is looking for a descendant of an element with ID `#main-nav` that has a class of `.navbar-default` when what you're really trying to select is an element with ID `#main-nav` that also has a class of `.navbar-default` so, to solve your issue, simply remove the descendant selector (i.e., the space), giving you:

```
#main-nav.navbar-default
```

You might also want to read up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line:

```
#main-nav .navbar-default
```

With this:

```
#main-nav.navbar-default
```

Answer (score 1):

The main-nav id `#main-nav` is on the same element as the navbar-default class `.navbar-default`

So to select it with CSS, you can use

```
#main-nav.navbar-default {
  // your code
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpqw2g39/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the main problem here is the selector which you are using.

**Your selector**

```
#main-nav .navbar-default {
color: white;
}
```

which means it sets the color white for element having class **.navbar-default** and also the parent **#main-nav**

But in your case the **.navbar-default** itself having the id **#main-nav** not its parent. That is why your selector is not working as required by you.

You need to change  your code as follows to work

```
  #main-nav.navbar-default {
    color: white;
    }
```